# PHP and JavaScript integration in Same Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Here's my form.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<textarea id="text1" name="ff1" >Monday 11 february</textarea>
<textarea id="text2" name="ff2" >Selected item is</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

on user clicking the submit button the data on the form is saved via (insert.php) to a database after this is accomplished how can I then open a new window?
I have a javascript function to do this, but am not advanced enough to call from the php

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you want this to behave?  Is the JavaScript function going to execute before the form post?  Is it going to potentially cancel the form post?  Do you want it to execute *after* the form post on the newly rendered page?  Please clarify.

Comment: the php is dtabase saving, and the javascript is function to then redirect to another webpage

Comment: @user3240828: If that's all the JavaScript code is doing then I recommend doing that from the server-side PHP code instead.  Issuing a redirect response is more standard than relying on JavaScript in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Give your form an ID and use the following JQuery:

```
$("#formID").submit(function( event ) {
  alert("Form submitted.");
});
```

If you want to stop the submit going through, as a form of validation, you can use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

With just pure JS:

```
function submitForm(e) {
    Form Processing Here.
}

var form = document.getElementById('formID');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onclick()` event.

Submit the form using JavaScript and call the function before the submission.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to stop the submit form from propagating. Then you can do something with javascript.